# (Ionic Framework) Npm Error when creating starter super template

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

Ok so, recently I am learning ionic v2 and I create a project using the super starter template. Then, i got an error

[image: error npm?]

And my ionic Info:

- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Windows 10
- Node Version: v6.11.0
- Npm version: 3.10.10
- Xcode version: Not Installed
- Ionic CLI Version: 3.4.0

How can i fix that? Thanks for your help

Comment: Try uninstall and re-install `npm`, `git` and `ionic`